# Skydrive API login type Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

I'm trying to find a way to differentiate how the user logs in to SkyDrive in an app, there are at least two way. One is a regular login screen where users enter their credentials then log in. The other one is the automatic Windows 8 login, which happens when users log in to Windows 8 with their live account; that automatically signs them in to SkyDrive in the Windows Store apps.

As far as I can tell, there's no way to tell the difference in the SkyDrive API, but if somebody knows a way, that would help a lot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the answer. The `LiveAuthClient` has a `CanLogout` property, which will be false if it's a Windows 8 login, and true if it's a regular credential form login.